# The width argument in CTkSegmentedButton not working

Tags: python, user-interface, customtkinter

```
log_sign = ['Login', 'Sign Up']
login_signupButton = ctk.CTkSegmentedButton(master=root, values=log_sign, command=login_signup, width=500, height=50)
login_signupButton.pack(pady=12, padx=10)
login_signupButton.set('Sign Up')
```

So while I'm working on a UI using customtkinter, I added a Segmented button which contains 2 values: "Login" and "Sign Up". But when I run the code, the segmented button is samll. So I tried to resize it with customtikinter's width and height arguments but only the height one works.

After that, i tried use other method like putting width's and height's values into a valuable but it still not work!